# PHP accelerators and static fields

Tags: php, class, static, state, accelerator

I would like to know about static (class) field representation within PHP interpreter.

For example, when you load a class in Java, static fields will be associated with that Class object; that means two applications running same JVM (and same classloader) will have some kind of shared global variable ;)

I'm just wondering, if I use some kind of PHP accelerator/opcode caching, what is that really cached? Is it just compiled bytecode, or a piece of VM state (responsible for storing class objects)?

It's because I'm afraid of static fields/singleton objects sharing between requests, etc.

P.S.: I'm really a PHP newbie, so I'm very sorry if the question is way too dumb :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An opcode cache will not change anything : each PHP script is executed by its own process *(or thread)*, in isolation from the others.

An opcode cache will only cache opcodes *(the PHP equivalent of JAVA's bytecode)*, and will nor store not related to the current execution of the script -- i.e. not any kind of "*VM state*".

This means your `static` variables will exist in one version for each execution of your PHP script, even if that script is executed several times in parallel ; and using or not an opcode cache will not change a thing.

Comment: Thanks very much, i'm relieved now :)

Comment: You're welcome :-) *(I would add that if opcode caching did change something that important, it would be major problem)*